# Ftp server Perfomance

Tags: iis, performance, ftp

i have a ftp server and asp.net application deployed (iis) on the same machine  the ftp server is on F drive and the application is on C drive hosted on iis . the application is used by 500 users daily through internet explorer. they are also going to upload and download the files from the application using the ftp server.
My question is there going to be any perfomance issue i.e is my server going to become slow. due to ftp server (used for upload and download from the application on the same mac

Answer (score 0):

Every reads and writes from and to the disk is an operation that the disk must handle. And a physical disk can only handle so many operation. So, yes, having additional service in operation will cause additional slow down.